# Error: maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded from external DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, dll

I am using an external dll in my asp.net C# application(4.0). In that dll, its calling a wcf service.

I am calling a method in the DLL named "Downloadfile()" for downloading a file as byte array.
For large files, I am getting an exception

**"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded".**

There is no endpoint configuration in my web.config because I am only reffering that DLL.

Then how to solve this scenario?

Kindly help.

Comment: Do you know if the exception is from the WCF service, or if it's from the external DLL? Do you have the source for the external DLL so that you can show us what line is failing? We can't very well help you with the problem if we don't know what that external DLL is doing.

Comment: for small files, the method working fine. I think this error due to the client app not allowing the downloading limit. There is no line specifications in the stack trace

Comment: Do you have any information regarding the DLL and what values it expects?  If it takes input from a config file, you can put those values in the client config and it will pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the third party application is using basic Http Bindings. You can over ride their settings by adding the following to your web.config.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MessageSizeBasic" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MessageSizeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Is there any paging routines in the third party DLL. because this solution only works if the files are less than 2 GBs in size.

Comment: This won't work unless it's assigned to an endpoint that the DLL recognizes.

Comment: If this is a dot net DLL, I would use dot dot peek or ilspy to decompile the DLL and post the code the DLL is using. The only fix might be to ask the 3rd party to resolve the issue for you.